# VueJS - Multiple js files in dist after building

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

When I run "npm run build", instead of getting the single build.js file, I'm getting 4 or 5 javascript files. Those javascript files have around 1MB in size. Why is this so?

Below is the folder structure

[image]

**build.js**

```
// https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs
require('./check-versions')()
require('shelljs/global')
env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var ora = require('ora')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

console.log(
  '  Tip:\n' +
  '  Built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
  '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
)

var spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

var assetsPath = path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory)
rm('-rf', assetsPath)
mkdir('-p', assetsPath)
cp('-R', 'static/*', assetsPath)

webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
  spinner.stop()
  if (err) throw err
  process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
    colors: true,
    modules: false,
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    chunkModules: false
  }) + '\n')
})
```

**webpack.prod.conf.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var env = config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    loaders: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap, extract: true })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: true
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin(utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    })
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

Comment: What does your build file look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .map files are source maps.

> A source map is a file that maps from the transformed source to the
>   original source, enabling the browser to reconstruct the original
>   source and present the reconstructed original in the debugger.
>   » [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map)

You don't neccesarily need them in production as they make the application much bigger and you shouldn't debug there anyway.

You can turn them off by setting `productionSourceMap: false`. Check your **config\index.js** file and look for this part:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    productionSourceMap: false
    ....
```

Answer (score 3):

All of these exist because your config file says they should.

`manifest.js` exists because of the config around:

```
// extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
// prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
```

`vendor.js` exists because of the config around:

```
// split vendor js into its own file
```

and the `.map` files are [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) intended for debugging:

```
sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap
```

Comment: I didn't get. I couldn't even find these files

Comment: @GijoVarghese Your screenshot **shows** those files. `app.4e9f5c2ff74accde707d.js` is your `app.js` file, with a hash to prevent browser caching. `manifest` and `vendor` are in your screenshot too. You should **understand** your Webpack config and what it's doing instead of just blindly copying and pasting it into your project and then getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the previous comment you get them because the default webpack configuration from vue-cli is setup to do that. Usually `app.js` contains all you custom code including `.vue` files and your main javascript files. `venodr.js` file on the other way if I'm not mistaken gathers all your imports from node_modules and puts them in this file.

So for example if you `import vueRouter from 'vue-router'` it will place the vue-router javascript into the `vendor.js` file because it was used like a plugin from npm. Since you don't change plugins to often in production, having them in a separate file is pretty useful because they get cached. Once you update something in your app and deploy it, the users will download the updated `app.js` which contains the code you've wrote for the app instead of downloading everything again (plugins + your app).

Having plugins in a separate js bundle is a common practice used in many frameworks/setups. (e.g .NET MVC bundles)